# NextJS getStaticProps is making mulitple requests to the same endpoint with fallback: true

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I've noticed my next application is making a ton of requests to my backend on page load. I'm using getStaticPaths and getStaticProps for when a path wasn't built at build-time so the fallback is used. The multiple requests don't happen with getServerSideProps or even in my dev environment. Only when deployed to Vercel. I've tried even creating a tiny application using JSONplaceholder API but viewing the Vercel function logs it appears it still makes multiple requests.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Home({ todos }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <p>Loading....</p>;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(todos)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [],
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const data = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`);
  const todos = await data.json();

  return { props: { todos }, revalidate: 10 };
}
```

Is this just how the fallback and cache work on Vercel?
Thanks

Comment: "my next application is making a ton of requests to my backend on page load" - Is this on a _single_ page load? Are you seeing the fetch request inside your `getStaticProps` happening multiple times for a single page request?

Comment: Yes, single page request.

Comment: This is expected on Vercel and _not_ an issue with your application. It doesn't cause any drop in performance. It's part of how our proxy handles incrementally generating pages.

Comment: It does cause a drop in performance for me as it's hitting my server with multiple requests for the same information causing some staggering. But if that's the way it works guess there's nothing I can do

Comment: @leerob this is causing a spike in usage with all the service providers that I hit during `getStaticProps`, even my logging service is getting flooded with logs because of it. I'm seeing a 3x usage increase due to this.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily make your whatever requests inside `getStaticProps()` builtin function because it is being run in build time and you can pass data of any requests through the props object such as code below

```
 export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  
      const res1 = await fetch('');
      const res2 = await fetch('');

  return {
    props: { res1,res2 },
  };
};
```